# How to Calculate Prices Based on the Number of Trips in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to create a query where if customers took 1 trip that day, then they would have to pay the price of a single ticket. If they took 2 trips on the day, then they would have to pay single * 2. And if they went on 3 or more, then they would have to pay for a day ticket. I managed to produce an output, but I don't understand why the query adds up the single tickets.

This is the query I tried.

```
SELECT ct.c_id, DATE(bt.start_time) AS date,
SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN tc.duration = 'Single' AND trip_count = 1 THEN tc.cost
        WHEN tc.duration = 'Single' AND trip_count = 2 THEN tc.cost * 2
        ELSE 0
    END
) +
SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN tc.duration = 'Day' AND trip_count >= 3 THEN tc.cost
        ELSE 0
    END
) AS total_cost
FROM CustomerTrip ct JOIN BusTrip bt ON ct.b_id = bt.b_id
JOIN TicketCosts tc ON tc.duration IN ('Single', 'Day')
JOIN(
    SELECT
        b_id,
        DATE(start_time) AS trip_date,
        COUNT(*) AS trip_count
    FROM BusTrip GROUP BY b_id, DATE(start_time)) 
    trip_counts ON ct.b_id = trip_counts.b_id AND DATE(bt.start_time) = trip_counts.trip_date
GROUP BY ct.c_id, DATE(bt.start_time);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the aggregation of tips an inner subquery, and the once aggregated use subqueries in the result set to calculate cost:

```
SELECT c_id, date, trips,
                   least(
                           (SELECT cost
                            FROM TicketCosts
                            WHERE duration = 'Single') * trips,
                           (SELECT cost
                            FROM TicketCosts
                            WHERE duration = 'Day')) AS cost
FROM
  (SELECT ct.c_id,
          DATE(bt.start_time) AS date,
          count(*) AS trips
   FROM CustomerTrip ct
   JOIN BusTrip bt ON ct.b_id = bt.b_id
   WHERE c_id = 1
     AND DATE(bt.start_time) = '2023-09-11'
   GROUP BY ct.c_id,
            DATE(bt.start_time)) AS day_summary
```

Result:

| c_id | date | trips | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-11 | 3 | 500 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xsE-e8kQ)

Answer (score 2):

We start with `JOIN` both `CustomerTrip` & `BusTrip`, which contain information about customers' trips and the corresponding bus trips. We use the `GROUP BY` clause to group the results by customer ID `c_id` and the date of the bus trip `DATE(bt.start_time)`. This grouping is needed to sum up number of trips a customer took on a particular day.

We can use the `CASE` statement to determine the cost based on the `count(*)` for each group.

```
SELECT ct.c_id, DATE(bt.start_time) AS date, 
  CASE
    WHEN count(*) = 1 THEN (SELECT cost FROM TicketCosts WHERE duration = 'Single')
    WHEN count(*) = 2 THEN (SELECT cost FROM TicketCosts WHERE duration = 'Single') * 2
    ELSE (SELECT cost FROM TicketCosts WHERE duration = 'Day')
  END AS cost
FROM CustomerTrip ct
JOIN BusTrip bt ON ct.b_id = bt.b_id
GROUP BY ct.c_id, DATE(bt.start_time) order by c_id;
```

Here is the [demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/J6B8tNmk?hide=12)
[image]

**Topics Covered:**

- [Data Retrieval:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/8.0/en/retrieving-data.html) The problem is about retrieving data from a database.
- [Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html): It includes the use of `subqueries` to fetch `ticket costs`.
- [Conditional Logic:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) The `CASE` statement is used to apply conditional logic to calculate costs based on the number of trips.
- [Aggregation:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564823) The problem involves aggregating data using the `COUNT()` function to count the number of trips.
- [Table Joins:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453762) `JOIN` is used to combine data from two different tables (`CustomerTrip` & `BusTrip`) based on a common column.
- [Filtering Data:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/condition-filtering.html) There are `WHERE` clauses used to filter data based on specific conditions.
- [Grouping Data:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) `GROUP BY` is used to group data by `customer ID` and `date`.